# libQt5Widgetsd.a , libQt5Guid.a and libQt5Cored.a : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, error-handling

I wanted to execute a project, and those 3 errors appear, does someone know how to resolve it ?

```
:-1: erreur : error: c:\Users\qt\work\install\lib\libQt5Cored.a: No such file or directory
```

Cordially

Comment: Seems like it's looking for the static libraries for Qt. Have you installed them? The cygwin/mingw ones?

Comment: I think yeah, can I still download them or I need to unistall all ?

Comment: Probably a wrong package, so uninstall and install the one you need.

Comment: How can I do that ? I never used qt :/

Comment: Like any other package, go on their website and download the package you need.